# How to use python for a webservice

Tags: python, web-services, parameters, scrapy

I am really new to python, just played around with the scrapy framework that is used to crawl websites and extract data.

My question is, how to I pass parameters to a python script that is hosted somewhere online.

E.g. I make following request *mysite.net/rest/index.py*

Now I want to pass some parameters similar to php like *.php?id=...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that would work. Although you would need to write handlers for extracting the url parameters in index.py. Try `import cgi` module for this in python.

Please note that there are several robust python based web frameworks available (aka [**Django**](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [**Pylons**](http://pylonshq.com/) etc.) which automatically parses your url & forms a dictionary of all it's parameters, plus they do much more like session management, user authentication etc. I would highly recommend you use them for faster code turn-around and less maintenance hassles.